# Java generics: Infering the type from another method?

Tags: java, generics, anonymous-inner-class

I have a decorator which I'd like to make generic in a special way.

Usage:

```
            new ExceptionHandler() {
                public <T extends IrcEvent> void  doIt( T msg, IrcBotProxy pircBotProxy ) throws Throwable {
                    plugin.onMessage( msg, pircBotProxy );
                }
            }.handle( msg, this.pircBotProxy );
```

I'd like the `T` to be infered from `.handle(...)`, which gets certain subtype - `IrcEvMsg`.

**How is that possible? Or do I need to parametrize the `ExceptionHandler` with a type to use?   (Java 7)**

Handler code:  (doesn't compile this way - says "Exceptionhandler doesn't implemetn `doIt(...)`")

```
public abstract class ExceptionHandler {

    public <T extends IrcEvent> void  handle( /*IIrcPluginHook plugin,*/ T evt, IrcBotProxy pircBotProxy ) {
        try {
            this.doIt( evt, pircBotProxy );
        }
        catch( NullPointerException ex ) {
            log.error( "Plugin misbehaved: " + ex, ex );
        }
        catch ( Throwable ex ) {
            if( System.getProperty("bot.irc.plugins.noStackTraces") == null ) {
                log.error("Plugin misbehaved: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } else {
                log.error("Plugin misbehaved: " + ex);
                if (ex.getCause() != null) {
                    log.error("  Cause: " + ex.getCause());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract <T extends IrcEvent> void doIt( T event, IrcBotProxy pircBotProxy ) throws Throwable;    

}// class
```

Comment: Define "Doesn't Work"? I don't see why this wouldn't (and I just wrote up an example using `<T extends List>` to test and that works just fine).

Comment: You seem to have an undefined `plugin` variable in your anonymous class.

Comment: *says "Exceptionhandler doesn't implemetn doIt(...)* ... I would suggest rechecking / saving your files and doing a clean / build. That would indicate you have a mismatched signature compared to what is posted here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with inferring the type the way you are doing it. Here is a very simple example that demonstrates:

```
public abstract class ExceptionHandler
{
    public <T extends List> void handle(T l) {
        this.doIt(l);
    }

    public abstract <T extends List> void doIt(T l);
}
```

...

```
public class Demo
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new ExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public <T extends List> void doIt(T l)
            {
                System.out.println(l.size());
            }

        }.handle(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "hi" } )));
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1

You state that you're getting a compile error of *"ExceptionHandler doesn't implement doIt(...)"* - you need to recheck your code and make sure you're passing the right params, make sure the files are saved, then clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define `T` at the class `ExceptionHandler` level:

```
public abstract class ExceptionHandler<T extends IrcEvent> {
    public void  handle(T evt, IrcBotProxy pircBotProxy ) {}
    public abstract void doIt( T event, IrcBotProxy pircBotProxy ) throws Throwable;    
}
```

This is only way to say "`T` used in  in `handle()` is the same `T` that is used in `doIt()`"

Comment: His code should work fine re: generics - inferring the way he's doing it is perfectly legal. The real problem, I suspect, has to do with the undefined `plugin` variable in his anon class.

Comment: Not really, I didn't want to clutter the code, but there's `        for( final IIrcPluginHook plugin : this.plugins ) {` around that.